# How should I store the aes key returned from server in browser?

Tags: javascript, session, token, aes

I am developing a website for a bank. And they are very serious about security. I firstly get a publicKey from the server, and create a random 16bit aes iv. And then I post the iv to the server it will return me the iv and aesKey. I use this key to encryt the following requests and decrypt the data from server.I stored the iv and aesKey directly in the sessionStorage or localStorage.But they told me that not safe enough! So how should I store them.If in a ios app, I know we can store them in the keychain. But now we are in the browser. And also I saw some people say store them in memory using a javascript closure. But that will losing them when refresh the page. Do anyone know a better way?

Comment: Do not send _anything_ sensitive (API or encryption keys, etc) to a browser. Period. Reason? All the code that runs in a browser is public and can be tampered with! All the security must be handled by your server. Also, don't trust _anything_ that is sent from a browser to your server, for the same reason.

Comment: Don't store the AES key, store the RSA public key. To encrypt, generate a random AES key and encrypt that. Note that you'd still have to rely on TLS, but you may use this to store data more securely at the bank, as the encryption will still be present after the transport security provided by TLS has been removed. If the bank is returning you an AES key *then they are doing it wrong*.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Thanks a lot. I will show you more details. Firstly, I call a API to get the rsa publicKey. Then I create a random 32 string, and use the publicKey to encrypt it.Let name it clientKey.Then I call another API sending the clientKey as a form field.The API return me a json with iv,and sessionKey. Then I use the publicKey to decrypt the sessonKey to the aesKey.I use the iv and aesKey to encrypt the request and decrypt the response. Is there any problem?

Comment: @MaartenBodewes do you me I can save the publicKey?It's that safe ?